# Customer created_at date is converted to UTC twice

Tags: customer, ce-1.8.1.0, model, date, timezone

I've found a problem with an extension we installed for registering new customers via social networks. Every customer that registers through the extension gets the wrong `created_at` date. We have our own registration module and that one works just fine.

My timezone is UTC -6, so we get something like this.

```
Current Time       Displayed          Stored
                   (Admin panel)      (Database)
2015-05-14 08:00   2015-05-14 08:00   2015-05-14 14:00   <<== our module (correct)
2015-05-14 08:00   2015-05-14 14:00   2015-05-14 20:00   <<== their module
```

It looks like the date is converted to UTC twice, so when it is converted back to GMT for display, it is off by 6 hours.

I read [this question](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/34464/timezone-issues-when-saving-new-model) and found out it's a Magento bug. But **how can I overcome this?** Why is it working in my module and not in the third party extension? I looked into their code and could only find `$customer->save()` being called once. I cannot set the correct date before saving since it will be overriden in the `_beforeSave` method of the customer model and I also can't edit the core model class. I don't think I can subscribe to the `customerAfterSave` event either since If I changed it there, the module that is currently working would be messed up.

Comment: Are you sure, they don't set the date somewhere? Because I can't imagine your model works and theirs dont :-) Or they use their own customer model? if you don't use magento methods to get the date but instead php `time()` etc. You get wrong results

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Comment: @kmdsax sorry mate, can't remember. I only remember it felt hacky. I haven't used Magento for years now.

Comment: I ran into this using IWD's Social Login extension, ended up using this patch to overcome: https://www.customerparadigm.com/magento-bug-magento-customer-create-date-juxtaposition/ It extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Backend_Time_Created and converts $date to a timestamp before using it in a function: $date = strtotime($date); I modified slightly so that it only touches the customer class:         if (!$object instanceof Mage_Customer_Model_Customer){
            return parent::beforeSave($object);            
        }